# Django: How to add one model as a foreign key to the other model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building my first API with Django-Rest-Framework and I'm a little stuck.

I have a model:

```
class Stage(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenth=20)
    application = models.ForeignKey(Application, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Account, null=True)
```

And a serializer as

```
class StageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    assignee = AccountSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)
    application = ApplicationSerailizer(read_only=True, required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Stage
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'assignee', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
              'application',)
    read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at', 'assignee',
                        'application',)
```

And a view as :

```
class StageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stage.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class = StageSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(creator=self.request.user)
```

I want to save the current application programmatically, like I am doing it with user. How to do this?

Comment: How do you define the "current application"?

Comment: I haven't actually. But I was thinking of storing it in user model, so that I cant retrieve it using 'request.user.current_application'. But is that a correct approach? @DanielRoseman

Comment: That depends entirely on what you actually mean with "the current application".

Comment: So the flow is like this: User creates an application. And a single user can create many applications. Now each application can have many stages. And stages can be created on the fly. So if the user selects one of the applications he has created, that is the current application. And the stages created here should belong to the current application @Sven

Comment: what specific error are you facing ?

Comment: This approach is against REST principles, because you must hold the information "application selected" between requests. I would suggest to model that state on the front end and then build your API in a verbose manner - put the application in the request, which will simplify your usecase.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Roba

Answer (score 0):

I think is an ident issue, please note that `class Meta` must be a subclass of `StageSerializer`. After that everything should work as expected.